# What is the correct order of Dark L articulation?

Tags: phonology, phonetics, laterals

I found the extract below on a website:

> The Dark L is the sound English speakers (the vast majority, anyway)
>   make when an L follows a vowel, and it’s articulated in what we might
>   call two ways at the same time:
>   1. The tongue-tip presses against the alveolar ridge – some people even slide it onto the back of their teeth.
>   2. Using the tip of the tongue for support, push the back of the tongue up, at the very back of the mouth, while voicing.

So according to the above extract:
The order of dark-l articulation is,

1. First, the tongue tip rises to touch the alveolar ridge.
2. Then the back of the tongue raises. (Velarization)

I thought it was the other way around:

1. First, the back of the tongue raises.(Velarization)
2. Then the tip of the tongue rises to touch the alveolar ridge.

Answer (score 3):

Your interpretation is more or less correct, as long as you are speaking of the initiation of those articulatory gestures and not their completion (the events are roughly simultaneous). [Sproat & Fujimura's study](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/dm/featgeom/sproat-fujimura93-L.pdf) using x-ray microbeam tech found that dorsal retraction and lowering begins earlier in dark *l* compared to light *l*. The article has a number of informative details about how dark *l* is actually produced.